# What all files/folders can be deleted before uploading to git/svn

Tags: android, git, android-studio, svn

My android app is having the usual Android Studio Folders but the size of certain folders exceeds the limit given by the IT for the projects which can be uploaded to the corporate repository.
Which All folders I can delete safely without breaking the build .I figure out build is the one. What else?
Below is the folder list :

```
- .gradle
- .idea
- build
- gradle
-keys
-res
-src
-Androidmanifest.xml
-ant.properties
-build.gradle
-custom_rules
-gradle.properties
-gradlew
-gradlew.bat
-local.properties
-proguard-project.txt
```

Comment: You can use this template as it is: https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Android.gitignore

Comment: Will it remove the folders as well which are already added like build,etc.? or do I have run any command before that?

Comment: Yes it will. If you add a `/` to the name (E.g. `foo/`), it will remove the folder called `foo`.

Comment: The question looks similar to many that ask about `svn:ignore` or `.gitignore` for Android Studio projects and it seems to me that it has been answered numerous times. Search StackOverflow for `[android-studio] ignore [git]` or `[android-studio] ignore [svn]` and use web search.

Answer (score 0):

Use this site

https://www.gitignore.io/ to generate a .gitignore file for android e.g

https://www.gitignore.io/api/android
These are files that you can safely ignore to put on version control and still able to build your project anywhere.